# Certificate chaining error for self signed certificates in HttpClient 4.5.x

Tags: jakarta-ee, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

One of my project was using http client 3.1.x and since it is deprecated now I upgraded the code to use the jar http client 4.5.2. After upgradation I'm not able to make any GET/POST request because of the certificate chaining issue.(The certificate is a self signed certificate.) Error log is as below...

```
[28/06/16 12:42:35:602 CEST] 00000025 SystemOut     O 2016-06-28 12:42:35.602 ERROR  MyProject                                1.0   WebContainer : 0               .. getData LOG_XXX_ZZZZ IOException occurred during getting ZZZZZZ data for url /myURL, message: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=xxxx, OU=yyyy, O=zzzz, L=wwww, C=qqqq is not trusted; internal cause is: 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=xxxx, OU=yyyy, O=zzzz, L=wwww, C=qqqq is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:22)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.tc.a(tc.java:465)
.
.
.
.
.
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.g: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=xxxx, OU=yyyy, O=zzzz, L=wwww, C=qqqq is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.b(e.java:45)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.b(e.java:106)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.d.a(d.java:5)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hc.a(hc.java:61)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hc.checkServerTrusted(hc.java:10)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hc.b(hc.java:14)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.hb.a(hb.java:66)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=xxxx, OU=yyyy, O=zzzz, L=wwww, C=qqqq is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.b(e.java:70)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=xxxx, OU=yyyy, O=zzzz, L=wwww, C=qqqq is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:111)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:595)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:357)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:298)
    at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.<init>(BasicChecker.java:108)
    ... 97 more
```

The code I'm using to execute the GET is as below. POST is also similar.

```
public int executeMethod(final HttpGet method) throws HttpException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(method);

    return httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
```

I don't know why the previous jar(3.x) was working without accepting the self-signed certificate but the new jar(4.5.2) is not working for self-signed certificate.

Also, *I don't want to alter the code to accept the self-signed certificate* as I have different requirements in different environments like (UAT/SIT/ET) some contain self signed certificate others contain proper certificate.